AutoScaling for Windows EC2 with Domain Joined
What's the correct way to perform auto scaling for windows EC2 with domain joined?
My current practice is to take AMI from my standalone deployment server (need to unjoin AD first), then update AMI to launch template and deploy to Auto Scaling Group with user data & lifecycle hook to handle domain join operation. This process is lengthy and occasionally might have issues with domain join failure thus causing downtime.
My question is this the correct way to do so? Is there any more straightforward way to deploy AMI to Auto Scaling Group without the need of unjoin domain and won't hitting computer name conflict on Active Directory?
